# How do you get descriptions into a docker image on a private registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've looked at the build command, the push command, and [various registry API calls](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#get-image-layer), but none of these have a feature which to apply a description.

[Descriptions seem to be implied from the remote API:](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#search-images):

(from the docs)

## Example request:

```
GET /images/search?term=sshd HTTP/1.1
```

## Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

[
        {
            "description": "",
            "is_official": false,
            "is_automated": false,
            "name": "wma55/u1210sshd",
            "star_count": 0
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "is_official": false,
            "is_automated": false,
            "name": "jdswinbank/sshd",
            "star_count": 0
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "is_official": false,
            "is_automated": false,
            "name": "vgauthier/sshd",
            "star_count": 0
        }
...
]
```

I can't find documentation on how to set them anywhere.

## Edit:

I turned up the following "question" type issue at github, which seems to imply it can't be done (this was Sept 2014, so it's *possible* it's been addressed)

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/561